# Trying to iterate over a word by using location of the letters as numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to basically make a hangman game. The playerLetter is compared to all the letters in the key word.

```
for i in currentWord:

      if playerLetter == letterList[i]:
          print('Yes, there is a ' + str(playerLetter) + ' in the word')
          answerList[i] = playerLetter
          win +=1
          yes = 1
```

where currentWord is the word (lets say its people if that helps), letterlist is equal to list(currentWord).
currentWord is a str, so when I do the for statement, i is a str, which I can't use to get to the numbered locations of letterList.

Edit: ended up using

```
for i in range(len(currentWord)):
```

which works, thanks everyone!

Comment: Use `for i in range(len(currentWord))`. As a side note, `list(letterList)` isn't necessary, you can iterate and access all the letters of `currentWord` just as you would with a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for index in range(len(currentWord))` to find the index of letters used in a currentWord

```py
currentWord = "python"
answerList = [""]*len(currentWord) # ["", "", "", "", "", ""]
playerLetter = 'p' # input(...)

if playerLetter in currentWord:
    for index in range(len(currentWord)):
        if currentWord[index] == playerLetter:
            answerList[index] = playerLetter
    print(f"Yes, there is a '{playerLetter}' in the word")
else :
    print(f"No, there is no '{playerLetter}' in the word")
```